# Custom Raspbian password too long to login before 60 second timeout

Tags: login, raspbian

I'm working on a project that uses the custom [Yodeck](https://www.yodeck.com/docs/display/YO/Creating+a+Yodeck+Player) image on a raspberry pi 3. I need to install some additional software on the box and they provide a username and password for console login. After booting I can drop to a login prompt with ctrl+alt+F2. At the prompt, I can enter the username and password, but the password is ~120 character hash and I can only enter about 70 characters before hitting a 60-second login timeout.

Is there any way to deliver the password to the prompt in a fast enough way to beat the timeout (other than memorizing and typing like crazy)? I'm also open to ideas for increasing the timeout. It sounds trivial, but after several attempts, it appears to be too short of a time to login in a repeatable manner.

Comment: Does it have network? Log in with SSH, and paste the password. Afterwards, set an authorized_key.

Comment: It does have a network, but the login doesn't appear to work via ssh. Good call, though.

Comment: When you do finally log in I'd set up some SSH keys. What OS are you accessing this box from?

Comment: macOS. And yes that's a great idea. I suppose I could try 40 times until I'm fast enough and set ssh keys. I'd prefer to make the solution repeatable for other boxes.

Comment: Is there a `LOGIN_TIMEOUT` setting in `/etc/login.defs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. The password that yodeck supplies is a hash of a password. You can change the password and then a ~120 character hash appears in the box. I mistook it to mean that my password was replaced with an auto-generated password, but it actually is just displaying a hash of your password. The password I set now works for ssh (even though the pw box shows a long hash).

Answer (score 0):

You can try simply copy+pasting the password.

For example, my main host is running Windows 7 and I use PuTTY to access my SSH clients. I am able to enter in my username on the host, and then right click on the terminal to paste my password. You may have to SSH to a jump box first for this functionality.

All in all, a 120 character hash is kind of annoying as a password. There are better ways to lock this host down such as SSH keys.